# Parse an object returned as JSON from API in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, azure

I have recieved a response object (res) in swift from `REST API`. It is of type. `__NSArrayM`. It contains a JSON format string which I want to parse.

```
{ JsonResult = "[ { \"IsAuth\":\"true\" } ]"; }
```

It is a long JSON String and I have shortened it for simplicity.

To parse a json, the object needs to be of type Dictionary but I can't cast the object of type `__NSArrayM` into it.

I searched a lot but can't figure out anyway to read this JSON string.

Additional: Whichever object I try to cast the response object. I get the error -

Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x107e86c30) to 'NSData' (0x107e86168) or whichever data type I cast into.

Comment: Don't try to replicate your Objective-C habits in Swift. For example, don't use NSArray/NSDictionary, use Swift collections instead, etc.

Comment: Yes I know, but it doesn't work either ways.

Comment: `To parse a json, the object needs to be of type NSDictionary` No. In JSON, the root object needs to be either an array or a dictionary. And do not confuse NSArray / Swift Array / JSON array. :)

Comment: `but it doesn't work either ways` What doesn't work? An array is not a dictionary. You can't magically cast one to the other...

Comment: It doesn't work work neither with NSDictionary not Dictionary. Though I correct myself.

Comment: Eric I understand that I can't cast the JSON into any random type.  Since my res object is of type __NSArrayM. I tried casting it into Dictionary but it gave error. That's what I am not able to figure out. res object contains a string which contains a JSON. I want to extract that JSON so that I can use it. Please help how can I do this.

Comment: @AyushOjha Ask the operator of the Rest API why a single dictionary is sent in an **array**.  That's also a hint.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. A REST API sends JSON strings, which you have to then deserialize into Cocoa objects, usually using the JSONSerialization class. In order to get the result of a REST API into an NSArray you must have already run some code. Put that code in your question.

Comment: It looks like what you have is a JSON string that contains a dictionary, and the value for the key JsonResult inside that dictionary is another JSON string, which is nuts. We need to see the code that got you to this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do this step by step.

You say you have an object named "res" which is of type `__NSArrayM` and which contains this thing:

```
{ JsonResult = "[ { \"IsAuth\":\"true\" } ]"; }
```

It means that *you* already have converted the JSON to an object, namely an NSArray.

*In this array that we don't see*, this thing you're showing us is a dictionary (that we will name "dict") with its value being a *String which itself represents another JSON object*.

Let's get the value using the key:

```
if let value = dict["JsonResult"] as? String {
    print(value)
}
```

Now "value" is supposed to be `"[ { \"IsAuth\":\"true\" } ]"`.

This is *a String* which represents JSON. To decode the JSON, we first have to make the string into data then we can decode:

```
if let data = value.data(using: .utf8) {
    if let content = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []),
        let array = content as? [[String: Any]]
    {
        print(array)
    }
}
```